# Javascript function returning the function itself?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

I have a small bit of code that is really giving me a headache.  All it needs to do is get a location (in this case an array representing a longitude and latitude).

planner.js:

```
var plan = function (lawnmower, yard) {
var currentPos = lawnmower.position;
alert(currentLong);
```

lawnmower:

```
var longitude = homeLongitude, latitude = homeLatitude;
var getPosition = function() {
    return [longitude, latitude];
};
that.position = getPosition;
```

When the alert gets called it returns getPosition after the equal sign.

Heres a [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdGAA.png)

I'm fairly novice at JS.

Comment: You are assigning the value of the function as opposed to assigning the result of it's `invocation`, which is represented by the `()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `()` when you call `getPosition`, so instead of assigning the result to `that.position` you're assigning the entire function:

```
that.position = getPosition(); //parenthesis!
```